# Run task in background mode in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, background

My app should download small piece of data from network every day (or week/month/etc, that is configurable) and save it to local file. Is that possible in iOS? Is it possible to run app in background mode, download data and stop it?

Comment: EveryDay! not Possible you have to remind Yesterday for Tomorrow or download. to run application in background is possible but not EveryDay!

Comment: You can make use of NSURLSession's download task with background mode/config to download the content in background :) You might find it useful if you can look into newsstand app category :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible only if your app has background mode enabled and it's in the background state. Background state is reached when user exit from your application and until garbage collector doesn't kill it for memory usage.

If you're goal is to download something every day / week / month in background even if user doesn't use app, that's impossible on iOS.

Comment: i have a problem that my app freezes in background state if it runs for more than 1 hour is their any solution ? i have a label which acts as a NSDate and it keeps running like a timer which displays the current time, any help

Comment: Run a background task for an hour is not a good solution. If this task updates a timer label you could find an alternative solution like remove the background task, save time in UserDefaults and make some logic on app reopening. But this doesn't regards to this question, you should post another question

Comment: @lubilis Downloading something every day / week / month in background even if user doesn't use app, that's POSSIBLE on iOS. send a silent push and create a background task. iOS will app app 3 minutes to run in background.

Answer (score 1):

While you can run task in background mode, there are few downside:

1. You can only control the minimum time between fetch, but cannot force it to happen on exact time (still, you can but you need to have push service), it will depends on how much your user use the app
2. If your app is killed, it wont run background fetch
3. It have time limit to run that task, as I know maximum is 10 mins(?)

[This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/143128/background-modes-tutorial-getting-started) tutorial is good to get you started

Answer (score 1):

Only apps that are registered for the tasks documented at this URL: [Background Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html) are allowed to run in background. iOS has a different approach compared to other systems like Android which supports the concept of background services. The idea is that apps running in background drain the battery and that's why Apple doesn't like too much the idea

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick one, since you're only doing a small task every day, why don't you use firebase? And have a main topic to tell everyone to check something at a particular time of day?

One thing though, you'll want to add some random to the timing of the request- or  every one of your users hits your server at once and cause an electrical fire. An alternative would be to have topics that you manage for regions or types of users, or some other way to split up groups of users.

I'm an Android developer, I would use a Sync Adapter to accomplish this kind of thing, but could also use an AlarmManager, where you would schedule a recurring alarm that executes an update basically.

This way it would be related to an update cycle on the user's end (every X hours from point of install) instead of the server. You could even give them the ability to set this themselves - but idk how that works on swift yet or if you can, just plugging Android ofc, but there must be a swift thing that does similar, unless it's locked off by the OS